# Integral of difference of density functions of two Continuous Random Variables goes to 0

Tags: probability, density-function, bias, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

The problem says :

> Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of continuous random variables with probability density functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ , and let $X$ be another continuous random variable with probability density function $f$ . Suppose, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , we have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise, as $n \to \infty$ . Then, prove that : $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big\vert ~f_n(x) - f(x)~\Big\vert~dx ~=~ 0$$

I have already figured out a proof which does not involve anything more than the expectation version of Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) which can be found here [in this paper](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ettkocz/teaching/1819/prob-notes.pdf). But my proof seems to be quite tedious. It'll be very good if someone can show a short and nice proof (Without using Measure Theory or the Integral version of DCT). In fact, if we go through [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), it is evident that  probably the Integral version of DCT solves this problem instantly, though we haven't been taught that. However, I was thinking if there's any short and nice elementary proof.